# Syntax error, insert ";" to complete FieldDeclaration

Tags: java, android, webview

#### String.xml

```
<string name="app_name">WebView Z/I</string>
<string name="http://www.cherkaoui.info/Spikal"> Cherkaoui</string>
```

#### R.Java

```
package com.firstest.android;

public final class R {
    public static final class attr {

    }

    public static final class drawable {
        public static final int ic_launcher=0x7f020000;
    }

    public static final class id {
        public static final int buttonUrl=0x7f050000;
        public static final int webView1=0x7f050001;
    }

    public static final class layout {
        public static final int main=0x7f030000;
        public static final int webview=0x7f030001;
    }

    public static final class string {
        public static final int app_name=0x7f040000;
        **public static final int http_//www_cherkaoui_info/Spikal=0x7f040001;**
    }
}
```

I have checked on the net, I have a problem on string.xml, but I don't know which one it is.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can't use `/` in an identifier - so this:

```
http_//www_cherkaoui_info/Spikal=0x7f040001
```

isn't a valid variable name. Change your XML to use a valid identifier.

Comment: Looks like an Android bug. Why would it replace '.' and ':' by '_', but not '/'?

Comment: @luiscubal: I don't know, but I also couldn't see anything in the documentation saying what's valid and what's not. So it may be by design rather than being an actual bug. Either way, it's easy enough to fix by just avoiding it...

Comment: @JonSkeet: You said "i don't know"?! Thats impossible! Holy cow! :P

Answer (score 0):

string name attribute must be a valid java identifier  do you consider this `"http://www.cherkaoui.info/Spikal`" as a valid java identifier ???

you can do this

```
<string name="http_www_cherkaoui_info_Spikal"> Cherkaoui</string>
```

then you can reference it in code

```
String str = getString(R.string.http_www_cherkaoui_info_Spikal);
```

Comment: So instead of "string" , I should use an URL is that right , or @string ?

Comment: The program is now compiling.
Thank you @Nammari !